# "Alarm Manager Set repeating" is not repeating under 1 minute?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set a background service with alarm manager.

```
  Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pending);
    //alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+15*1000  , 15*1000, pending);
```

But it is not working every 15 seconds. Sometimes works after 20 seconds, sometimes after 1 minute. But, When I set 1 minute(60*1000)it is not also the exact time. it's close.(1 minute 4 second, 1 minute 13 second)  Why is that happing?

Comment: It may be this: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Comment: @sinek What about whatsupp,instagram? How do they work to get incoming message. Do you know that?

Comment: if i understand your question, messaging apps like whatsapp use sockets and push notifications to deliver messages in real time to the client, rather than the client checking if any new messages are available

Comment: @MichaelStoddart Can you give an example code for this. I'm new in this.

Comment: @Furkan a quick google of how to create a messaging app will tell you everything you need to know...

Comment: Yes, they use push notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Repeating alarms are by default inexact since API 19.

A workaround is to set a simple exact alarm in x seconds and then set another alarm recursively when the alarm is triggered. This code works for me like a charm. All you need to do in addition is define the service in your XML:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
```

From the main activity you start it like this:

```
AlarmReceiver alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
alarm.setAlarm(this);
```

The service in which you schedule the alarm is the same in which it is also received:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        setAlarm(context);
        //Put whatever you want to do below here
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L + 5L) *1000L, pi); //Next alarm in 5s
    }
}
```

Comment: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))